# Run IE6 and IE7 side-by-side on Vista

Tags: windows-vista, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7

I have a need to run IE6 on my Vista machine that natively runs IE7.
Can someone please help me with set-up / configuration steps?

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Retagged this, I think running ie on vista is very programming related, in general web developers are the ones that need this feature

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) -- it allows you to test pages in IE 5.5 - 8b2.

Answer (score 1):

Try ie6eolas_nt.zip from http://browsers.evolt.org/?ie/32bit/standalone . I use it on XP; haven't tried Vista.

Comment: +1 good link. See comments of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487737. 6 down, 9 to go (1 per day)

Answer (score 1):

Just use http://www.xenocode.com/browsers/

You can run older version of IE in Vista and Windows 7 :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have IE7 installed, using [Multiple IE's](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE) will let you install past versions without any conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple IE [does not work](http://tredosoft.com/IE6_For_Vista_Part_1) on Vista, you are stuck using a VM of sorts for full IE support. This is critical if you need to test your javascript or debug through CSS.

I managed to use [AndLinux + Wine](http://www.samsaffron.com/archive/2008/04/27/Running+IE6+on+Windows+Vista) to get this working, but honestly I think the VMWare/Virtual PC/Virtual Box route is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the multiple IE, but it has javascript problems which aren't their in the normal version.

[The IE team advices](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/11/30/ie6-and-ie7-running-on-a-single-machine.aspx) to use the I[nternet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Images](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en). These are virtual pc images with different IE versions.

Supported versions:

- IE6 on XP SP3
- IE7 on VISTA
- IE7 on XP SP3
- IE8B2 on XP SP3

For other IE versions you could make your own virtual image.